# change y axis values in angular chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart

I am creating a project in angularjs. In my project i am using angular chart.I want to change the y axis values of the chart,but i dont know how can i do this. Here is my code:

In Controller:

```
 $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
        //  $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
          $scope.data = [
            [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
          ];
```

In html:

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data"
  chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true" 
  chart-click="onClick" >
</canvas>
```

Comment: what errors you are getting.... more information needed..  its good if you make some demo for your question...

Comment: Now only default value shown on y axis. I want to show my own values

Answer (score 1):

I used an Angular-Charts bar-chart on a recent project and discovered that there is a way of changing the y-axis setting.

What you need to do, is add an extra value at the end of the `$scope.data` array(s) that sets the minimum value you want on the Y-axis; in my case it was zero, but it can be any other number you need. So long as you don't add any further `chart-labels`, this extra data value doesn't generate its own bar, but it does stop a real value acting as the y-axis baseline.

Hope that helps.